# retrofit header authorization not working

Tags: android, api, retrofit, retrofit2, retrofit2.6

`*`**i am tried to send token header using "Autorization" but response return empty. postman it's working. i used retrofit library. i tried two ways**`

````
interface EtrApi {
    @POST("getLoads")
    fun getLoads(@Header("Authorization") accessToken: String
    ): Call<LoadResponse?>?
}
interface EtrApi {
    @Headers(
        "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8",
       "Accept: ",
        "Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJUaGVfY2xhaW0iLCJhdWQiOiJUaGVXVkIiwiaWF0IjoxNjcwODQ0NDk5LCJuYmYiOjE2NzA4NDQ1MDksImV4cCI6MTcwNjg0NDQ5OSwiZGF0YSI6eyJkcml2ZXJfaWQiOiIxOSIsImRyaXZlcl9uYW1lIjoibWsgdGsiLCJkcml2ZXJfZW1haWwiOiJta0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJyb2xlIjoiZHJpdmVyIn19.NL_285_OaBPBYJncb9_oFKuvgMgSjfFkJcxIJMzS7Xc"
    )
  @POST("getLoads")
    fun getLoads(): Call<LoadResponse?>?
}

 val quotesApi = RetrofitHelper.getInstance().create(EtrApi::class.java)
            if (token != null) {
                Log.e("token",""+token)
                quotesApi.getLoads(token)
                    ?.enqueue(object : Callback<LoadResponse?> {
                        override fun onResponse(
                            call: Call<LoadResponse?>,
                            responsez: Response<LoadResponse?>
                        ) {
                            Log.e("Responsestring", responsez.body().toString())

                            if (responsez.isSuccessful) {
                                if (responsez.body() != null) {
                                    //  var json = Gson().toJson(response.body())
                                    progressDialog.dismiss()
                                }
                            } else {
                                progressDialog.dismiss()
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoadResponse?>, t: Throwable) {
                            Log.e("Responsestringerr", t.toString())
                            progressDialog.dismiss()
                        }
                    })
            }

```*`
````

Comment: There is no a rejected response at all? And make sure is your authorization use a Bearer token?

Comment: actually it's normal token. i tried bearer token method also. always return response null

Comment: What is the response like when you run in Postman? Maybe you map it incorrectly to `LoadResponse`? Maybe share the response from Postman and your `LoadResponse` class.